# Convert Elixir string to integer or float

Tags: elixir

I need to convert a string to a floating point value or an integer. There was no method such as,

```
string_to_integer
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Check [**`Integer.parse/1`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/1) and [**`Float.parse/1`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html#parse/1).

Comment: Note that this will return a tuple (if successful) and not the integer directly. If you want to do that, see @Szymon Jeż answer with `String.to_integer/1`

Comment: Is there any reason to use `Integer.parse/1` over `String.to_integer/1`?

Comment: @IanVaughan `Integer.parse/1` returns a `:error` atom if unsuccessful.
`String.to_integer/1` throws a `(FunctionClauseError)`.

Comment: To add to Jonathan's point,  `String.to_float("0")` throws an error, while `Float.parse("0")` returns `{0.0, ""}`. This allowed me to use a single function when my string might not include a decimal point.

Answer (score 58):

In addition to the `Integer.parse/1` and `Float.parse/1` functions which José suggested you may also check `String.to_integer/1` and `String.to_float/1`.

Hint: See also `to_atom/1`,`to_char_list/1`,`to_existing_atom/1`for other conversions.

Answer (score 36):

Thanks folks on this page, just simplifying an answer here:

```
{int_val, ""} = Integer.parse(val)
```

as it validates that the entire string was parsed (not just a prefix).

Comment: This will throw an error if the val is not purely an integer. I added a case on the result to ensure the conversion was successful. The second clause can be generic to catch :error or a non-empty second string as you don't care much whether the input was "x3" or "3x".

Answer (score 27):

There are 4 functions to create number from string

- String.to_integer, String.to_float
- Integer.parse, Float.parse

`String.to_integer` works nicely but `String.to_float` is tougher:

```
iex()> "1 2 3 10 100" |> String.split |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
[1, 2, 3, 10, 100]

iex()> "1.0 1 3 10 100" |> String.split |> Enum.map(&String.to_float/1)
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_float("1")
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1270: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1270: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
```

As `String.to_float` can only handle well-formatted float, e.g: `1.0`, not `1` (integer). That was documented in `String.to_float`'s doc

> Returns a float whose text representation is string.
>
> string must be the string representation of a float including a  decimal point. In order to parse a string without decimal point as a float then Float.parse/1 should be used. Otherwise, an ArgumentError will be raised.

But `Float.parse` returns a tuple of 2 elements, not the number you want, so put it into pipeline is not "cool":

```
iex()> "1.0 1 3 10 100" |> String.split \
|> Enum.map(fn n -> {v, _} = Float.parse(n); v end)

[1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 10.0, 100.0]
```

Using `elem` to get first element from tuple make it shorter and sweeter:

```
iex()> "1.0 1 3 10 100" |> String.split \
|> Enum.map(fn n -> Float.parse(n) |> elem(0) end)

[1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 10.0, 100.0]
```

Answer (score 12):

You can convert it to a char_list and then use the Erlang `to_integer/1` or `to_float/1`.

E.g.

```
iex> {myInt, _} = :string.to_integer(to_char_list("23"))
{23, []}

iex> myInt
23
```

Comment: How to use it in functions? My best solution is `fn q -> {v, _} = Float.parse(q); v end` which I don't like. I like to use it in `Enum.map`, e.g. `list |> Enum.map(&String.to_float/1)` but string.to_float doesn't work for integer numbers?

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using `Integer.parse/1` is that is will parse any non-numeric part of the string as long as it is in the tail end. For example:

```
Integer.parse("01") # {1, ""}
Integer.parse("01.2") # {1, ".2"}
Integer.parse("0-1") # {0, "-1"}
Integer.parse("-01") # {-1, ""}
Integer.parse("x-01") # :error
Integer.parse("0-1x") # {0, "-1x"}
```

Similarly `String.to_integer/1` has the following results:

```
String.to_integer("01") # 1
String.to_integer("01.2") # ** (ArgumentError) argument error :erlang.binary_to_integer("01.2")
String.to_integer("0-1") # ** (ArgumentError) argument error :erlang.binary_to_integer("01.2")
String.to_integer("-01") # -1
String.to_integer("x-01") # ** (ArgumentError) argument error :erlang.binary_to_integer("01.2")
String.to_integer("0-1x") # ** (ArgumentError) argument error :erlang.binary_to_integer("01.2")
```

Instead, validate the string first.

```
re = Regex.compile!("^[+-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$")
Regex.match?(re, "01") # true
Regex.match?(re, "01.2") # true
Regex.match?(re, "0-1") # false
Regex.match?(re, "-01") # true
Regex.match?(re, "x-01") # false
Regex.match?(re, "0-1x") # false
```

The regular expression could be simpler (e.g. `^[0-9]*$`) depending on your use case.

Answer (score 5):

```
Decimal.new("1") |> Decimal.to_integer
Decimal.new("1.0") |> Decimal.to_float
```

Comment: I got this error: ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Decimal.new/1 is undefined (module Decimal is not available)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to convert a string to whatever numeric type is within the string & remove all other characters, this is probably overkill, but will return a float if its a float or an int if its an int or nil if the string does not contain an numeric type.

```
@spec string_to_numeric(binary()) :: float() | number() | nil
def string_to_numeric(val) when is_binary(val), do: _string_to_numeric(Regex.replace(~r{[^\d\.]}, val, ""))
defp _string_to_numeric(val) when is_binary(val), do: _string_to_numeric(Integer.parse(val), val)
defp _string_to_numeric(:error, _val), do: nil
defp _string_to_numeric({num, ""}, _val), do: num
defp _string_to_numeric({num, ".0"}, _val), do: num
defp _string_to_numeric({_num, _str}, val), do: elem(Float.parse(val), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_integer/1` and `to_float/1`

```
String.to_integer(numstr || "0")
String.to_float(numstr || "0.0")
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? Indeed, several mention these functions already. **Given this, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?