# Get a single float value from a string in elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there a method that takes in a float string and converts it to a single float. It must also handle strings without `.` like `"1"`

`String.to_float` does not handle `"1"`

```
iex(5)> String.to_float("1")
** (ArgumentError) argument error
:erlang.binary_to_float("1")
iex(5)> String.to_float("1.0")
1.0
```

`Float.parse` handles `"1"`, but returns a tuple.

```
iex(4)> Float.parse("1")
{1.0, ""}
```

Comment: The tuple is so it can return the float that it parsed, and the remainder of the string that it didn't know what to do with. That is expected with a parser. Just use the first value from the tuple. Or create a wrapper function if you plan on doing it a lot and don't care for the remainder string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Convert Elixir string to integer or float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576658/convert-elixir-string-to-integer-or-float)

Maybe you should use something like

```
{res, _} = Float.parse("1")
```

or

```
elem Float.parse("1"), 0
```

Comment: It might be helpful to know why the second element of the tuple can be discarded here.

Comment: `iex(1)> Float.parse("56.5xyz")
{56.5, "xyz"}`

Comment: I'd prefer to use `{res, ""} = Float.parse(float_as_string)` if `float_as_string` is not expected to have trailing rest. This way, the code fails fast if your assumption is not met.

Comment: Do you know why `String.to_float("1")` is not working?

Comment: As per the documentation, [String.to_float](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/String.html#to_float/1): `string` must be the string representation of a float (Remember that Floating-point numbers must have at least one digit before and after the decimal point). If a string representation of an integer wants to be used, then `Float.parse/1` should be used instead, otherwise an argument error will be raised.